# I can't parse the page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I can't parse ad titles. I want to parse pages from OLX (It's like ebay only in the CIS countries), and write them to a csv file. I already wrote two functions, one gets the page, the other looks for names, I wanted to test it, but I have some kind of error, I will be grateful if you help me.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

HOST = 'https://www.olx.ua/'
URL = 'https://www.olx.ua/d/zhivotnye/sobaki/'
HEADERS = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}


def get_html(url, params=''):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='css-19ucd76') # Parsing the entire ad.
    animal = []

    for item in items:
        animal.append(
            {
                'Title': item.find('div', class__='css-u2ayx9').get_text(strip=True) # Name parsing.
            }
        )
   
 return animal
html = get_html(URL)
print(get_content(html.text))
```

`css-19ucd76` - This is an ad.
`css-u2ayx9` - This is the title.

```
Это ошибка: 'title': item.find('div', class__='css-u2ayx9').get_text(strip=True)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz7Uv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid selecting on dynamic part in HTML as such classes and change your strategy to select more static parts like tags or by id.

Used `css selectors` get the cards `soup.select('div[data-cy="l-card"]')` and selected title by `h6` tag name:

```
for item in soup.select('div[data-cy="l-card"]'):
    animal.append(
        {
            'Title': item.h6.get_text(strip=True) # Name parsing.
        }
    )
```

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

HOST = 'https://www.olx.ua/'
URL = 'https://www.olx.ua/d/zhivotnye/sobaki/'
HEADERS = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}


def get_html(url, params=''):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    animal = []

    for item in soup.select('div[data-cy="l-card"]'):
        animal.append(
            {
                'Title': item.h6.get_text(strip=True) # Name parsing.
            }
        )
   
    return animal
html = get_html(URL)
print(get_content(html.text))
```

###### Output

```
[{'Title': 'Бульдог французский'}, {'Title': 'Цуценя д/ш німецької вівчарки, дівчинка від Чемпіонів.'}, {'Title': 'Цуценята Лабрадор (золотистий ретривер)'}, {'Title': 'Два мини мальчика'}, {'Title': 'Мальтипу Девочка'}, {'Title': 'Бесподобный кукольный мишка мальтипу F1 мини беби фейс'}, {'Title': 'Собачий поводок   10 метров SOLOGNAC'}, {'Title': 'Йорк Девочка КСУ'}, {'Title': 'Красуня Мальтіпу'}, {'Title': "Джек Рассел тер'єр ( цуценята)"}, {'Title': 'Щенки Той Пуделя. Документы Харьков'}, {'Title': 'Продам Той пудель'}, {'Title': 'Щенки мопса,мопсики детки,мопс'}, {'Title': 'Мальчик 6,5 месяцев'}, {'Title': 'Продам йорка девочку'}, {'Title': 'Цвергшнауцер-подниматель настроения'}, {'Title': 'Померансккий шпиц девочка.'}, {'Title': 'Ошейник для собак из полиуретана SOLOGNAC'}, {'Title': 'Очень крутая девочка Американский булли'}, {'Title': 'Девочка померанского шпица'}, {'Title': 'Німецька вівчарка'}, {'Title': 'Немецкая овчарка'}, {'Title': 'Продаю щенков'}, {'Title': 'Щенки мопса предварительная бронь'}, {'Title': 'Розпродаю свою коллекцию пионов по доступным ценам'}, {'Title': 'Готовы для бронирования бигли'}, {'Title': 'Продам цуценят дратхаар (німецький жорсткошерстий лягавий)'}, {'Title': 'Вівчарки  цуценятя 12.06.22 року народженя'}, {'Title': 'Собачки Підбультерер'}, {'Title': 'Крошка той пудель'}, {'Title': 'Шпиц мишка'}, {'Title': 'Неймовірні  цуценята  Акіта-іну'}, {'Title': 'Сибірські хаскі'}, {'Title': 'Чихуахуа МИНИ 3 месяца'}, {'Title': 'Английского бульдога щенки. КСУ. Киев'}, {'Title': 'восточно европейская овчарка'}, {'Title': 'Очаровательная микро девочка'}, {'Title': 'Щенки аргентинского дога'}, {'Title': 'Металлический доберман'}, {'Title': 'СТАФфтерьер породные чистокровные щенки АСТ'}, {'Title': 'Цуценята німецької вівчарки робочого розведення. Чемпіонські крові.'}, {'Title': 'Померанский шпиц'}, {'Title': 'французский бульдог lux'}, {'Title': 'Французский бульдог носитель флаффи девочки'}, {'Title': 'Супер щенок пудель той'}, {'Title': 'Породные шоколадные щенки Питомник.'}, {'Title': 'перспективный мальчик немецкой овчарки'}, {'Title': 'Девочка померанского шпица'}, {'Title': 'Щенки МАЛЬТЕЗЕ , мальтийская болонка'}, {'Title': 'питомник.'}, {'Title': 'Сладкая модуленция и светлый редкий окрас. Девочка-Померанка'}, {'Title': 'Мальчик маленький предлагается к бронированию'}]
```